# How to fix this lamp?

Tags: lamp

I really only need to screw the nut onto the bolt, but both are stripped, and parts of the end of the bolt have chipped off, so I can't. Would superglue work? I can't replace the nut or remove the washer without removing the wire also (which I don't know how to do).

[image]

EDIT: This is a table lamp:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. Please [edit] to give us a broader pic of the lamp so we have a better idea of what we're looking at. If the bulb & glass shade are supported by this nut/bolt, I wouldn't want to count on superglue holding it in position. If you'll give us a pic of the inside of the shade, showing the bulb socket (remove the bulb), we can probably tell you how to remove the socket. Once it's out replacing it with one that doesn't have stripped threads (and a new nut, too), is pretty straightforward and probably your best bet.

Comment: Nipple looks broken, unless it just pulled through the lamp.  I think the washer with the ridges is internally threaded, to thread onto the nipple.  You may simply need to replace the nipple, but I can't see enough detail in your photo to be sure.

Comment: This really falls under small appliance repair and is therefore off topic. See the [help].

Comment: Why does the power plug have a rectangular-ish hole in the back ?   Is that a Neon to show the device is powered ?

Comment: It's just the cord. I don't know why. The lamp is about 75 years old ;)

Comment: I'd guess, @Criggie that this is a replacement plug (it looks pretty chintzy to me) and that whoever did the replacement didn't put the little cap on.

Comment: I would superglue it, around the tube, so as to not glue the cord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your photo shows a power cord with a local wall plug, so presuming this is a **Desk Lamp**.

The nut appears to exist just to hold the metal stem down into the glass of the base. Without that nut, presumably the whole metal core will slide upward if pulled, along with the lamp holder and switch assembly.

The metal "backbone" is likely required to provide support and stiffening for the glass spheres and keep them in-line.  It will also protect the mains cable in the event of the glass breaking.

**Solution** I would use some 2-part epoxy to push into the vertical hole in the glass, up beside the metal backbone.  Then I would refit the nut and washer as it is, with epoxy holding it in place.  Clamp for a day or so and then test.

Avoid epoxying the power cable if you can.  Note this will be a final repair and difficult to undo.  Also, you may be able to see the epoxy through the base glass piece so consider using a colour-matched or clear epoxy.

Comment: Thank you, that's helpful. The glass over that part is frosted a bit so the epoxy shouldn't be too visible.

Answer (score 0):

There's really not much you could do to repair that lamp without disassembling the plug so you can slide the damaged parts off the wire. The 1/8 lamp nipple looks damaged, and the end of it may be broken off, but it's hard to say just from the photos. Whether the nipple is replaced or not, it definitely needs some sort of bushing for the lampcord where it emerges from the bottom. Most lamp shops would have sturdy plastic nuts that would serve both as a bushing and to replace the damaged little knurled nut. The cord could be routed through the channel in the base and secured in place with hot-melt glue of proper color. Otherwise, every move of the lamp will be a fiddly process of getting the cord into the channel and not under the flat base, making the lamp all wibbly-wobbly.